# Why doesn't the Guideline work when I use CardView within ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I hope to design a UI to dsiplay two columns with latest ConstraintLayout layout, so I use Guideline, it can work when I use Code B (Please see Image B),

But Code A can't display two columns (Would you please see the Image A) after I add CardView control to the layout, what's wrong with my code?

**Image A**
[image]

**Image B**

[image]
**Code A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Hello" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Jack" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Hello" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Jack" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `Guideline` to work, it needs to be the child of a `ConstraintLayout` and a sibling of the `view` that is going to use it as a constraint.

In your case, setting the `CardView` as the root view and the `ConstraintLayout` inside it would solve the issue.

See this XML as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      >

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="100dp"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:text="Hello"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:text="Jack"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```